# Space after clearing TextField in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I am making an application with JavaFX and wondering why there is a space after I clear my TextField. The following code is where this bug occurs.

```
    TextField field = new TextField();  

    field.setPromptText("Start typing!");

    field.setOnKeyTyped(e -> {

        if (Character.isWhitespace(e.getCharacter().charAt(0))) {

            System.out.println(field.getText());
            field.clear();
        }
    });
```

This was a simple fix after adding a simple if statement.

```
    TextField field = new TextField();  

    field.setPromptText("Start typing!");

    field.setOnKeyTyped(e -> {

        if (Character.isWhitespace(e.getCharacter().charAt(0))) {

            if (Character.isWhitespace(field.getText().charAt(0)))
                field.setText(field.getText().substring(1, field.getText().length()));

            System.out.println(field.getText());
            field.clear();
        }
    });
```

However, this does not tell me why a space is there after I clear the text `field.clear();` or set the text to an empty String `field.setText("");`. Is there a way to clear the text without adding a space afterwards or is that just a bug with TextFields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `handle()` is called before the character is added to the textfield. Everytime you type, the following things take place :

- The handle method is called, it checks the character, clears the textfield.
- The textfield then adds the character to the textfield after returning from the method.

There is a method called as `consume()` which stops an events further propagation. You can use this whenever the condition is true and this will prevent the space from getting added.

```
if (Character.isWhitespace(e.getCharacter().charAt(0))) {
   System.out.println(field.getText());
   field.clear();
   e.consume();
}
```